# При старте приложения используется 86% оперативной памяти(HeapSize)

Tags: android, утечка-памяти, android-support-library

Я разрабатываю приложение для Андроида(платформа Xamarin).
На текущий момент это приложение является прототипом(внутри нет ничего тяжелого).
Было добавленна библиотека app7compat support,так же был заимплементен тулбар с DrawerLayout.
Провожу тесты на устройстве Samsung Galaxy **S4 Active** и если корректно понимаю,то это скорее всего баг\глюк, т.к. при запуске приложения Android Device Monitor показывает следующее :
[image]

Как такое вообще возможно? Моя активити содержит:

1. Тулбар(с Drawer layout)
2. Пару контролов,таких как **Imageview**/**ImageButtons**

Как я говорил раньше,это происходит сразу после запуска. Чем же может быть занята память на 86%, если даже нету никаких цпу\гпу вычислений?
Почему это происходит?

Comment: Вычисления не занимают память. Они занимают процессор. А вот что анимает память...

Если честно, то я думаю, что это просто Xamarin. Ну не нужно на этой поделке писать приложения.

Но если хочется разобраться - делайте дамп памяти и смотрите, чем именно она занята.

Comment: 1. это `Xamarin`, в котором багов и ликов больше, чем звезд на небе. 2. heap расширится по мере необходимости. Как только будет надо больше, он станет больше.

Comment: @KoVadim про вычисления имелось ввиду,что нет никаких преобразований\конвертаций связанных с изображениями(которые жрут процессор и загружаются в РАМ телефона). Но что самое смешно, планируется это реализовать... :)

Comment: @metalurgus возможно. Спрошу на их форуме,правда там не шибко отвечают :(

Comment: Думаю, что на форуме xamarin вряд ли будут говорить, что у них плохой продукт.

Comment: Вот похожая [тема](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41935). Кроме того попоробуйте создать чистое приложение и посмотреть сколько оно занимает. И на нескольких девайсах/емуляторах с разными экранами и версиями.

Comment: @anber к сожалению, то немного другая платформа(Xamarin.Forms, а у меня Xamarin.Android :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это нормально. Приложение занимает 86% от выделенной в данный момент для него памяти.

Много конечно, но не смертельно.

Гляньте лучше сколько памяти всего может быть выделено. В случае андроид это делается так:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();
Log.v("onCreate", "maxMemory:" + Long.toString(maxMemory));
```

или так:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
int memoryClass = am.getMemoryClass();
Log.v("onCreate", "memoryClass:" + Integer.toString(memoryClass));
```

Если не ошибаюсь для S4 это 192 Mb (201326592 b)

Comment: Только что попробовал(первым методом). Показывает следующее  134217728

Comment: Хмм, странно 128 Mb, меньше чем на Galaxy S4 Play Store Edition. Попробуйте еще в манифесте выставить флаг largeHeap и посмотреть что будет?

Comment: установил largeHeap = true,имеем следующее 536870912